# Easiest way to automate a small R program that sends me an SMS using twilio API

Tags: r, server, twilio

I have written a small script that scrapes some data from a website, formats it, and sends a summary to me via SMS using the twilio API. This is roughly what the code looks like:

```
# load packages
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(twilio)
library(cronR)

# twilio credentials
account_sid <- "xxxxxxx"
auth_token <- "xxxxxxx"

# save twilio credentials to correct environment 
Sys.setenv(TWILIO_SID = account_sid)
Sys.setenv(TWILIO_TOKEN = auth_token)

# build function to check for open seat applications
check_seats_fcn <- function(.x) {
  url_ <- "https://labour.org.uk/activist-hub/governance-and-legal-hub/selections/parliamentary-candidate-application-form/"
  read_html(url_) %>% 
    # select a list of "rows"
    html_elements("div.two-column-list__body > div") %>% 
    # iterate though rows, if there are missing values, 
    # seat and deadline would still be correctly aligned
    # list of named lists plays well with dplyr::bind_rows()
    map(\(row_div)
        list(seat     = html_element(row_div, "div.col > h6") %>% html_text(),
             deadline = html_element(row_div, "div.col > ul > li") %>% html_text())) %>% 
    bind_rows()
}

# call function and get ready to send as text 
open_seats <- check_seats_fcn() %>%
  mutate(col = paste0("\n", seat, " (", deadline, ")")) %>%
  select(-seat, -deadline) %>%
  pull()

# convert char vector to single string value
body <- paste(open_seats, collapse = " ")

# send text with currently live seat selections
cmd <- twilio::tw_send_message(
  to =   "+44XXXXXXXXXX",
  from = "+44XXXXXXXXXX",
  body = body
)

# set up cron job to run every 48 hours
cronR::cron_add(
  cmd, 
  frequency = 'daily', 
  id = 'job1', 
  at = '12:01', 
  days_of_week = c(0, 2, 4, 6), 
  ask = FALSE
)
```

The `check_seats_fcn` will run but if you want to test the bit that sends the text message you'll need your own credentials for twilio.

As you can see, i'm using a cronjob to automate sending the text messages once every two days. However, this only works when I have my computer on and doesn't reboot after i turn it off.

I have no dev experience but would appreciate any pointers on the simplest way to ship this (i don't mind paying a small fee) so that it automatically runs from a cloud server with R on it somewhere.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Having a server running 24/7 to send an SMS message every two days is probably not the most efficient method. You will probably want to use AWS lambda or similar, which supports cron jobs. There's an R package which makes this easier which looks good though I haven't used it. Essentially you put your script and the R runtime in a docker container - [this](https://discindo.org/post/deploy-an-r-script-as-an-aws-lambda-function-without-leaving-the-r-console/) is a helpful resource.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Trying this out now. I think you've set me on a much simpler path which is exactly what I was hoping to get